# iOS app with background fetching feature crashes in background with exception 0xbad5bbad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, crash

I am working on adding the background fetching feature to my iOS app. It uses Core Data as sole storage and the fetch I am executing adds some information (kind of 'fetch notifications') to database.

After implementing everything and successfully testing it with simulated fetches from Xcode's debug menu I decided to perform some field experiments - I have set UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum, launched the app, sent it to background and left my 5s alone for a couple of hours.

After waking the phone I switched the app back to foreground and noticed that it has removed user's account I was signed in to - the only way it could have happened was by purging the Core Data's content, what obviously is a very critical problem. In organizer's device logs pane I have found the following crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: FE34EA01-4DA0-4315-DDA8-33DC8CD0CAA1
CrashReporter Key:   37018631ac51170b5781f4d9fcd950db64f89180
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2
OS Version:          iPhone OS 7.0.5 (11B601)
Kernel version:      Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 27 23:08:32 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2423.3.12~1/RELEASE_ARM64_S5L8960X
Date:                2014-02-10 13:38:11 +0100
Exception Code:      0xbad5bbad
Reason:              my.apps.bundle should be bgContentFetching but he is task suspended instead

Thermal data unavailable

Frontmost process PID:    16
Jetsam Level:              0
Free Pages:            15483
Active Pages:         107037
Inactive Pages:        51702
Purgeable Pages:        4459
Wired Pages:           40181
Speculative Pages:      4166
Throttled Pages:           0
File-backed Pages:     82649
Compressions:         106865
Decompressions:        11520
Compressor Size:       36896
Busy Buffer Count:         0
Pages Wanted:              0
Pages Reclaimed:           0

Process 0 info:
    resident memory bytes:  935444480
    page faults:               21741
    page-ins:                      1
    copy-on-write faults:          0
    times throttled:              65
    times did throttle:           37
    user   time in task:       42962.479797 seconds
    system time in task:           0.000000 seconds

Process 0 kernel_task threads:
thread 0x1 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0xffffff80006775cc
    thread priority:               92
    Base thread priority:          92
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont: 0xffffff80003442b4
    user   time in thread:     1.300313 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x2 TH_RUN|TH_IDLE 0
    thread priority:                0
    Base thread priority:           0
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont: 0xffffff80002f7f4c
    user   time in thread: 20862.364775 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x3 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0xffffff80002f3d2c
    thread priority:               95
    Base thread priority:          95
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont: 0xffffff80002f3d2c
    user   time in thread:     3.103439 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds etc . . .
```

Now the **0xbad5bbad** part looks pretty critical...
Should I somehow intercept such possibility of my app being suspended when system decides to allow it to fetch? Any other ideas of solving this?

**Update** - added the background fetch code:

My delegate contains the following property (the approach - suggested by the fellow iOS dev - got used in a couple of properly working apps):

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completionHandler)(UIBackgroundFetchResult fetchResult);
```

Fetch code:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(alertFinished:) name:kNotification_Alerts_Method object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(alertFailed:) name:kNotification_Alerts_Method_Fail object:nil];

    [[AlertManager sharedInstance] updateItems];

    self.completionHandler = completionHandler;

}

-(void)alertFinished:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:kNotification_Alerts_Method object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:kNotification_Alerts_Method_Fail object:nil];

    NSArray *alerts = [[AlertManager sharedInstance] getUnreadAlerts];

    if([alerts count] != 0)
    {
        for(Alert *alert in alerts)
        {
            //scheduling local notifications basing on the fetched alerts
        }

        if(self.completionHandler)
        {
            self.completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(self.completionHandler)
        {
            self.completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
        }
    }
}

-(void)alertFailed:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:kNotification_Alerts_Method object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:kNotification_Alerts_Method_Fail object:nil];

    if(self.completionHandler)
    {
        self.completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
    }
}
```

The AlertManager is configured to report failure unless the data is received and parsed in 15 seconds (in order to avoid problems with background fetching time limitation).

By the way - the code USUALLY works properly, but I can not really allow such crash to happen on production...

Comment: Can we see your background fetch code?

Comment: I have added the fetch code to my question.

Comment: Some feedback based on your code. [Apple's WWDC 2013 videos][1] suggest to not use completionHandler as a property. Instead, you pass it along to the methods that handle it.


  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/

Comment: @apalvai Thank you for your suggestion, but having the completionHandler as a property is actually the core aim of this solution - it would not be possible to pass it to the multilayered and multithreaded part of the app responsible for fetching data without some serious modifications of the whole structure in order to get it back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

You may have fixed your issues by now, but we fixed one issue with background fetch by copying the completionHandler (if you're saving it as a property as you're doing).  For example:

```
self.completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];
```